# How to create a table which is shown in attached figure

Tags: tables

Can anybody help me to generate a table as shown in the figure? As I am writing a research book and the following are my overall packages. I hope you guys have a solution which is suitable for my packages also.

Thank you very much in advance

```
    \documentclass[12pt,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\parindent0pt 
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.20}\normalsize 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage[intlimits]{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amssymb} 
\usepackage{icomma} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{theorem} 
\numberwithin{equation}{section} 
\usepackage{commath} 
\usepackage{bm} 

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 


\definecolor{dunkelblau}{rgb}{0,0,0.5} 
\definecolor{americanrose}{rgb}{1.0, 0.01, 0.24}
\definecolor{babyblue}{rgb}{0.54, 0.81, 0.94}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{cerulean}{rgb}{0.0, 0.48, 0.65}

\numberwithin{figure}{section} 

\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}  
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2} % Paket zur Bearbeitung der Kopf- und Fu�zeile
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead[]{\headmark} 
\ohead[]{\pagemark} 
\cfoot[\pagemark]{}
\setheadsepline{0.4pt} 
\setlength{\headheight}{1 cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{1 cm}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref} 

\usepackage{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{bibgerm} % deutschsprachiges Literaturverzeichnis
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{leftidx} 
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Quellcode} 
\numberwithin{table}{section}

\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\cal{\@fontswitch\relax\mathcal}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\mit{\@fontswitch\relax\mathnormal}

%\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
%\setcellgapes{3pt} % due to 
%\usepackage{siunitx}
```

%%%%%%% My try

```
\begin{table}[hbt]
\centering
\captionabove{Acceleration relation with Force}
\begin{tabular}{||p{2.5cm}||p{4.0cm}||p{1.5cm}||p{2cm}||p{2cm}||}\hline
para 1 \&  para 2  & Standard deviation (std) of measurements data & std (exponential) & std (Parabolic)  & Pearson coefficient\\\\ \hline\hline
Acceleration  \& Force & 9.0916 & 8.3552& 8.9866 &0.9397 $(0.000)$\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table} \label{Force}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you try so far? Please reduce your document preamble to the part relevant for writing your table. It seems that `makecell` package can be handy for writing your table.

Comment: Hi there, I added my try. I am new on latex. Packages which i have uploaded are from my university. I do not know which is for table. Thank you in advance for your kind help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I prefer table without vertical lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\parindent0pt
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.20}\normalsize

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[hbt]
\centering
\captionabove{Acceleration relation with Force}
 \label{Force}
\begin{tabular}{p{25mm} *{4}{S[table-format=1.4,
                                input-symbols=()]} }
    \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Standard deviation (std)}
        &   {\multirow{2.4}{*}{\makecell{Pearson's\\ 
                                       coefficient}}}   \\ 
    \cmidrule{2-4}
P 2 & {Data 1}  & {Data 2}  & {data 3}  &               \\
    \midrule
\multirow{2}{=}{Acceleration \& Force} 
    & 9.0916    & 8.3552    & 8.9866    &  0.9397       \\ 
    &           &           &           & (0.0000)      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @zarko. It is working. Can you help me with how I can adjust the column width? my table is going out of the page.

Comment: @maths, table in my answer is inside of text borders. I use document setup from your code fragment. You probably change something in y MWE. To help you, we need MWE, by which you test my solution.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using [makecell](https://ctan.org/pkg/makecell)’s `\diaghead{}` and nested `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[DIV=12]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array, caption, makecell}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}



\begin{document}


\begin{table}[hbt!]
\small
\centering
\captionabove{Acceleration relation with Force\label{Force}}
\begin{tabular}{|wc{3cm}|*{3}{wc{2.7cm}|}c|}
\hline
\diaghead{\hskip0.19\hsize}{\&  para 2}{para1}   & 
\multicolumn{3}{wc{8.1cm}|}{\begin{tabular}[t]{wc{2.7cm}|wc{2.7cm}|wc{2.7cm}}
\multicolumn{3}{wc{8.1cm}}{Standard deviation (std) of measurements}\\\hline
data & std (exponential) & std (Parabolic) \end{tabular}} &
\begin{tabular}{c}
Pearson \\ coefficient 
\end{tabular} \\\hline
\begin{tabular}{c}
Acceleration  \\\& Force 
\end{tabular} & 9.0916 & 8.3552& 8.9866 &0.9397 $(0.000)$\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

One idea it's on use of [`diagbox`](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/diagbox/diagbox.pdf). How you change distances on `x{..cm}` or in `width` and `height` of `\diagbox` will need a change in one or other of those parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{diagbox} %table split headers

\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|x{2cm}|x{1.5cm}x{1.5cm}x{1.5cm}|x{1.5cm}|}
\hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\diagbox[width=2.4cm,height=3\line]{$P_1$}{$P_2$}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Standard Deviation} & \multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack{Pearson's\\Coeff}}\\
    \cline{2-4}    
    & Data 1 & Data 2 & Data 3 & \\
    \hline
    Acceleration \& Force &&&& \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much